# I use Linux Lite Live with persistent memory and I'm unable to remove/disable cdrom repository in it. What to do?

Tags: ubuntu, repository, live-usb, persistence

I created a Linux Lite Live with persistent memory using mkusb. I set the persistent memory to 100%.

I need to remove the cdrom repository from Linux Lite Live so that I don't have to be annoyed by messages like

```
Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

while I'm trying to update packages.

The problem is, when I remove or disable the cdrom repository in Software and Updates, it comes back enabled after reboot. It means I have to remove it every time I have to use `sudo apt-get update` after a reboot. It really annoys me.

I have already tried to delete it in `sources.list` file. The deleted lines come back after reboot.

What do I have to do to make it vanish forever from my repository list?

Output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Linux Lite 5.0 - Release amd64 dists/ InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Linux Lite 5.0 - Release amd64 dists/ Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease               
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:12 http://repo.linuxliteos.com/linuxlite emerald InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                           
E: The repository 'cdrom://Linux Lite 5.0 - Release amd64 dists/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the features of Linux Lite, that differ from Ubuntu, but I think "Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs" indicates, what might be possible to do. Let us hope that someone who uses Linux Lite will see your question and help you solve this problem. Otherwise maybe you can ignore that error message. Or does it mean that you need something that must be upgraded that way?

Comment: @sudodus I don't need to update anything using cdroms. I'm just annoyed by that message. I thought that the error message was interrupting the process but apparently it wasn't. I guess I will not have any problem if I continue to update packages while ignoring that message.